# EntityManagerFactory per session in an application-managed

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

i have to change the **default schema at runtime** in my multi-tenant **SaaS** application. (Shared Db - Seperate schema). Basically every customer is gonna have their own schema (designed this way because of some confidentiality reasons) and based on their **login credentials**, they will be hooked up to a specific schema once after login.

I am using JPA2.0 and eclipselink as Persistence provider.

i thought of creating a **Singleton EMF** which is application-scoped and passing schema-name to createEntityManager when i am creating method-scope EntityManagers but have noticed that schema property can just be passed to **createEntityManagerFactory()** so i have to create one EMF for every session (@SessionScope) and create Em from the EMF in every business method.

does the design make sense for the scenario i described ?

any suggesstions ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with such multi-tenant setups, but you're going from one unique EMF shared by everyone to one EMF per user.

You're going too far. The correct granularity IMO should be one EMF per database schema. There's no reason for two users (and thus two HTTP sessions) using the same schema to have two different EMFs.

Comment: I agree.  You would be best off to have your own cache of EntityManagerFactorys keyed by schema.

Comment: how could i create one EMF per database schema programatically ?
i know i can put them in persistence.xml but what happens if i add one more tenant to my app ? i think i would have to restart the app server at this point ?

Is there any way i can add the new 'persistence-unit' to persistence.xml and kinda reloading the app-server(sun-glassfish) instead of restarting. Because i can't handle restarting the app every time i add another tenant.

One more thing is; lets say i will have 500 tenants, that is gonna mean i will have 500 'persistence-unit' Would it be ok for performance ?

Comment: also another requirement for me is every tenant is gonna have different users logging in with different permissions. that is why i thought EM creation should be SessionBased.

please let me know if i am wrong at any point

thanks in advance

Comment: That is a completely different (albeit important) question. Based on your question, I thought this was a problem you already solved. As I said, I don't have any experience with multi-tenant apps, and I can't answer. AFAIK, multi-tenancy support is a difficult problem, and is a work in progress, that is not standardized yet in JPA.